# Force refresh on login/logout in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, refresh, browser-cache, w3-total-cache

I am relatively new to PHP and can't figure out how to refresh all pages after log in or log out from a wordpress site?

When a visitor goes to my site some content appears. However, when the user logs in, the page loads some additional content (only logged in users can see). Since, I am leveraging browser caching, even after logging in the visitor sees the old (cached) copy of page. If I do `Ctrl`+`F5` the page shows what it ideally should...

In short I am looking for a way to refresh all browser cached pages after log in and log out operations.

I have activated W3 Total Cache to use browser caching.

PS: Please do not suggest a plugin.

Comment: `refresh all pages after log in or log out` -- it's not quite clear what you're asking. Please add more detail.

Comment: Added more details :)

Comment: When the user logs in, doesn't that automatically refresh the page? Or are you serving a cached version of non-logged-in-user and want to refresh that? If you are using W3 Total Cache, you can disable caching for logged-in-users.

Comment: I disable caching for logged in users but still I'm facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these lines in the top of the your wordpress theme Index file,

```
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```